# QT 5.2.1 Quick 1.1 on Android

Tags: android, c++, qt, debugging

**Hello, when I run simple, empty project on android, I got this application output:**

```
I/Qt JAVA (20079): DEBUGGER: waiting for pong at /data/local/tmp/qt/debug-pong-org.qtproject.example.client, attempt 4
I/Qt JAVA (20079): DEBUGGER: go to sleep
I/Qt JAVA (20079): DEBUGGER: waiting for pong at /data/local/tmp/qt/debug-pong-org.qtproject.example.client, attempt 5
I/Qt JAVA (20079): DEBUGGER: go to sleep
I/Qt JAVA (20079): DEBUGGER: waiting for pong at /data/local/tmp/qt/debug-pong-org.qtproject.example.client, attempt 6
I/Qt JAVA (20079): DEBUGGER: go to sleep
I/Qt JAVA (20079): DEBUGGER: waiting for pong at /data/local/tmp/qt/debug-pong-org.qtproject.example.client, attempt 7
I/Qt JAVA (20079): DEBUGGER: go to sleep
Could not load shared library symbols for 71 libraries, e.g. /system/bin/linker.
Use the "info sharedlibrary" command to see the complete listing.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?Unable to find dynamic linker breakpoint function.
GDB will retry eventurally.  Meanwhile, it is likely
that GDB is unable to debug shared library initializers
or resolve pending breakpoints after dlopen().I/Qt JAVA (20079): DEBUGGER: waiting for pong at /data/local/tmp/qt/debug-pong-org.qtproject.example.client, attempt 8
I/Qt JAVA (20079): DEBUGGER: got pong /data/local/tmp/qt/debug-pong-org.qtproject.example.client
D/libEGL  (20079): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
D/        (20079): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb883f7e8, tid 20079
D/libEGL  (20079): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
D/libEGL  (20079): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
W/EGL_emulation(20079): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
D/OpenGLRenderer(20079): Enabling debug mode 0
```

**then if i click on the page, that i have :**

```
A11y (26034): EXCEPTION in dispatchHoverEvent for Accessibility: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
I/dalvikvm(26034): threadid=1: stack overflow on call to Ljava/lang/Class;.getPublicConstructorOrMethodRecursive:LLL
I/dalvikvm(26034):   method requires 40+20+12=72 bytes, fp is 0xa02b7330 (48 left)
I/dalvikvm(26034):   expanding stack end (0xa02b7300 to 0xa02b7000)
I/dalvikvm(26034): Shrank stack (to 0xa02b7300, curFrame is 0xa02b73b4)
W/Qt A11y (26034): EXCEPTION in dispatchHoverEvent for Accessibility: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
W/dalvikvm(26034): Stack overflow on call to interp (req=76 top=0xa02bd000 cur=0xa02b7324 size=24576 Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;.<init>)
```

Can  somebody help me?

Comment: @user1095108 i think thats a bit harsh and not constructive. Qt does more good than harm, if you dont like the framework, you are free to turn to some other solution. If you like it, it is a GREAT plus to be able to help and contribute. OP: can you post your code or steps to recreate your problem? which operating system are you on? does this also happen with a "real world" project?

Comment: @x29a I know it's harsh, but it's also true. You bite the bait, choose `Qt`, something goes wrong, you file a bug, fix gonna be ready soon? In your dreams. Even, if you post a patch, it takes forever. Try it and you'll see and we'll also see, if this won't make you angry. The OP is probably using an "exotic" tablet, that no one bothered to test `Qt` on, so OP let this be a lesson to you about `Qt`, you could have wasted more time.

Comment: x29a -this is my code : #include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    return app.exec();
}

Comment: I test it on Android 4.2.... if i  run it on windows, then i have normal work without any problems.....